# Proving hint given for this Lebesgue integration question

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $\{n_{k}\}$ is an increasing sequence of positive integers and $E$ is the set of all $x \in (-\pi, \pi)$ at which $\sin(n_{k}x)$ converges. Prove that $m(E)=0$. Hint: For every subset $A$ of $E$, $\int_{A} \sin(n_{k}x)dx \to 0$ and $2 \int_{A} (\sin(n_{k}x))^{2}dx = \int_{A} (1 - cos(2n_{k}x)dx \to m(A)$ as $k \to \infty$.

I am only having trouble proving the hints, not the main question itself. This question has been asked before, specifically in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247799/prove-the-set-of-which-sinnx-converges-has-lebesgue-measure-zero-from-baby-ru) thread. However, I am not comfortable with the response given. In particular, how would I go about deriving the hints without the use of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma? I am interested by the proposed method to use Bessel's inequality applied to $\chi_{A}$, but I am not sure how this would even work.

I'd appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first hint can be derived from [Parseval's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParsevalsTheorem.html) (which is an application / case of Bessel's inequality); note that $\int_A \sin(n_k x) dx$ is the imaginary part of the $n_k$-th Fourier coefficient of $\chi_A$, and $\chi_A \in L^2[-\pi,\pi]$. Thus,

$$\|\chi_A\|_{L^2} = \|(a_k)_{\ell^2} \| = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} |a_k|^2$$

where $a_k$ denotes that $k$-th Fourier coefficient of $\chi_A$. Since the sum is finite,

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} |a_k|^2 = 0 \implies \lim_{k \to \infty} \operatorname{Im} a_k = 0$$