# Puzzles in a proof

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

From a previous link in MSE: [Prove the set of which sin(nx) converges has Lebesgue measure zero (from Baby Rudin Chapter 11)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247799/prove-the-set-of-which-sinnx-converges-has-lebesgue-measure-zero-from-baby-ru), the question states

> Suppose that $\{n_k\}$ is an increasing sequence of positive integers and $E$ is the set of all $x$ in $(-\pi,\pi)$ at which $\sin(n_kx)$ converges. Prove that $E$ has Lebesgue measure zero. Hint: For every subset $A$ of $E$, $\int_A \sin (n_kx) dx$ tends to zero, and $2\int_{A} \sin^2(n_k x)dx$ tends to the measure of $A$.

My question is that does this question assume that $E$ is measurable? How to check the measurability of $E$? And what will be the value of limit of such cosine functions?

$EDIT$: The answer is given in the comment...

Comment: Yes, $E$ will be measurable. Actually, if $(X,\mathcal{M})$ is any measurable space, and $\{f_k\}$ is a sequence of real-valued measurable functions on this space, then the set of $x \in X$ such that the sequence $(f_k(x))$ converges will be a measurable set.

Comment: How to prove that?

Comment: Let $g=\limsup_k f_k$, and define $h_k=|g-f_k|$, so $h_k$ is always measurable. Notice that $f_k(x)$ converges iff $h_k(x)$ converges to $0$, so we just need to prove that $E:=\{x \in X : h_k(x) \to 0 \}$ is measurable. Notice that $E$ can be written as $$\bigcap_k \bigcup_N \bigcap_{n \geq N} h_n^{-1}(-2^{-k}, 2^{-k})$$ i.e, the set of all $x$ such that $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}; \forall n\geq N: |f_n(x)|<2^{-k}$

Comment: Do you have some easier method that works in this situation?

Comment: Let me try to think of one. BTW, in that last line in the above comment, it should say $|h_n(x)|<2^{-k}$, not $|f_n(x)|<2^{-k}$.

Comment: @Shalop Thanks so much, and there seems to be no easier method in proving this fact. p.s.  asked TA today, who also presented the method you gave.

Comment: Yeah sure no problem :)